# Expo - standalone APK crashing when running on physical device; app working on expo-cli

Tags: apk, react-native, expo

First off, I'm new to react-native so please excuse my missing knowledge regarding troubleshooting.

I have built a basic app using Expo, which runs perfectly fine when I run `expo start` and scan the QR code to run it on my physical device.

I then ran `expo build:android` in my terminal and selected apk to create an apk file. It installs, but when I try to open the app on my phone, it crashes straight away. I'm not sure why this happens, or how to troubleshoot it.

Some steps I have taken:

- Reinstalled expo-cli
- Reinstalled react-native
- Ran `npm-update`
- Manually downgraded my sdkVersion to 37.0.0 in my app.json file (as suggested by online forums)

Here is my app.json file:

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "FactApp",
    "slug": "FactApp",
    "sdkVersion": "37.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.kmdevops.factapp",
      "versionCode": 2,
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-7529073010403742/8555991419"
      }
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.yourcompany.yourappname",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0"
    },
    "description": ""
  }
}
```

And here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.1",
    "expo": "^37.0.12",
    "expo-ads-admob": "~8.1.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.1.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.3.9",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.7.0",
    "react-navigator": "0.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked your console if it shows any errors when you are running your app by scanning the QR code?

Comment: There don't appear to be any errors. Are you referring to the errors that pop up in yellow once I run the app using the QR code?

Comment: Yellow ones are warnings. They do not cause on crashing the app. Do you get any blue screen when your app crashed? If yes, please upload a screenshot of that blue screen and the log.

Comment: Hi, I just ran the app using expo, and it works perfectly. I can't see any errors at all on my terminal. Is there another way to check for errors?

Comment: I mean, when you ran the apk, do you get a blue screen when it is crashed?

Comment: No, it simply says "FactApp keeps stopping". When installing the app it says "Blocked by Play Protect. Play Protect doesn't recognise this app's developer. Apps from unknown developers can sometimes be unsafe." then it says "Ok" and "Install Anyway". I press install anyway

Comment: Seems like your app is blocked by the OS. Can you please try installing it on another device?

Comment: Just upgrade expo-cli. Expo somethimes cause this error. I think this is expo's error. so upgrading to latest expo-cli fix this error.

Comment: Hi, neither of these solutions seem to work unfortunately. I also disabled play protect on my physical device and the app won't open

Comment: So I've installed the apk on an android emulator and it installs with no issues, but I still have the same error

Answer (score 1):

So I created a fresh new app with expo-cli and the resulting APK crashed so I figure it's an issue with expo. I used react-native cli to create an apk for this app and it works with no issues

Comment: and how i can leave expo enviroment and build it with react-native cli?